# Java 2D Array for chess board not working

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, chess

i'm trying to make a simple chess board with Strings as my chess pieces in a 8x8 2D Array. But the output is not what I want, as the Array just goes down. (Sorry for my language. I'm not so good at programming) Here's my code:

```
public class ChessBoard {
    String[][] board = new String[8][8];
    public void fillBoard() {
        //Fills the empty spaces
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                board[i][j] = " ";
            }
        }

        // Rooks
        board [0][0] = "R";
        board [0][7] = "R";
        board [7][0] = "R";
        board [7][7] = "R";

        // Knights
        board [0][1] = "N";
        board [0][6] = "N";
        board [7][1] = "N";
        board [7][6] = "N";

        //Bishops
        board [0][2] = "B";
        board [0][5] = "B";
        board [7][2] = "B";
        board [7][5] = "B";

        //Queens
        board [0][3] = "Q";
        board [7][3] = "Q";

        //Kings
        board [0][4] = "K";
        board [7][4] = "K";


        //Pawns
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            board[1][i] = "P";
            board[6][i] = "P";
        }
    }

    public void presentBoard() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                System.out.println(board[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

The output is then something like:

```
R
N
B
Q
K
B
N
R

P
P
P
P
P
P
P
P

P
P
P
P
P
P
P
P

R
N
B
Q
K
B
N
R
```

But the intention was this output:

```
R N B Q K B N R
P P P P P P P P






P P P P P P P P
R N B Q K B N R
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
I have changed

```
public void presentBoard() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            System.out.println(board[i][j] + " "); //this line
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

But nothing happens.

Comment: Try changing `System.out.println(board[i][j]);` to `System.out.print(board[i][j] + " ");` :)

Comment: If my answer helped you, feel free to click on the gray tick below the answer score. If not, edit your question and add the information about what's wrong

Comment: It's not working. It's the same output.

Comment: Can you check once again? It's definitely not the same.

Comment: I have checked. It's the same output as before.

Comment: @NikolajEgholkJakobsen you didn't remove two letters: ln from this single place - I've marked them with red on pictures.

Comment: @NikolajEgholkJakobsen can you see the difference? Just copy my whole code and paste in your IDE. You'll see the difference.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for:

```
public void presentBoard() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            System.out.print(board[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

`System.out.println()` prints in a new line. On the other hand, there is `System.out.print()` which stays in the same line.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You beat me to it by 10 seconds. :) +1

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thanks for being fair. Many users would have posted and downvoted the others immediately